# How to get GCC9.x or latest gcc with Go compiler on a windows 2000 machine

Tags: gcc, cygwin, windows-2000

I need to build a tool written in Go. Go doesn't support windows 2000 so I want to fall back on latest GCC compilers with built in support for Go (gccgo). I have cygwin 1.7 on windows 2000 machine (oracle virtual machine) (Perhaps I need a cygwin expert to assist with getting latest gcc in this setup.)

I could not find a step by step process to follow. I tried building gcc 9.2 on cygwin 1.7 on windows 2000 but it crashes.

Errors I get when I run ./configure from gcc 9.2 source code on cygwin 1.7 (windows 2000) :

```
./configure: line 1932: cannot create temp file for here document: Device or resource busy
./configure: line 1944: cannot create temp file for here document: Device or resource busy
./configure: line 1979: cannot create temp file for here document: Device or resource busy
./configure: line 2141: cannot create temp file for here document: Device or resource busy
./configure: line 2145: cannot create temp file for here document: Device or resource busy
./configure: line 2149: cannot create temp file for here document: Device or resource busy
./configure: line 2153: cannot create temp file for here document: Device or resource busy
./configure: line 2157: cannot create temp file for here document: Device or resource busy
./configure: line 2161: cannot create temp file for here document: Device or resource busy
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh ./config.sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I build my own personal build of GCC for Windows (see http://winlibs.com) and I have tried GCC 9 with Go language enabled, but I get:

```
configure: WARNING: go not supported for this target
configure: error:
The following requested languages could not be built: go
Supported languages are: c,brig,c,c++,d,fortran,jit,lto,objc,obj-c++
```

So it looks like Go is not supported yet by GCC on Windows...

Let's hope GCC 10, which should be released soon does support Go.

Comment: GCC 10.1.0 is now available on http://winlibs.com/ .

I checked and Go is still not supported by GCC on Windows.

Comment: Updated: still hoping to get the MinGW-w64 build of GCC to support Go.
Latest attempt with GCC 12 snapshot builds go, but libgo fails to build, possibly because of issues in gccgo. My findings have been reported here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105302